Parse CSV string auto convert to number issue
I am trying to convert JSON data into CSV using papa parse. In my JSON I have a field article id which is a string type but when showing in CSV it automatically converts it into a number which creates the issue that my article is big in number but the column size of Excel is small which my number which should be shown like this 490750661  is showing like this 4.9E+08 . The same goes for my date field also. The number is indicated correctly when I manually increase the width of the column.
Default view

After manually increasing the width

I tried explicitly specifying those two fields as numbers but it still didn't work.
const flatData = dataJSON.flatMap((order: any) =>
        order.line_items.map((item: any) => ({
          order_id: order._id,
          article_id: item.article_code.toString(),
          quantity: item.quantity,
          merchant_id: order.merchant_id,
          date: dayjs(order.createdAt).format("YYYY-MM-DD").toString(),
        }))
      );


A trick to use would be that add some string to that number like if it is 490750661 then it should be 490750661abc. in this manner it would stay a string in CSV too. then after parsing it using papaparse, remove the abc from that number and you get the original number in string form

Add at the beginning of the string value the apostrophe ' character.
Example:
'490750661

In your code:
article_id: "'" + item.article_code.toString(),

Notice that when you open the Excel file, a warning on the cell will appear - saying: Number stored as text. You have to click on said warning and select the option: Convert to number.
If you don't desire this outcome, then, post an issue on their GitHub page.

@KrishnaBiswal if your alternative solved your question, please, post an answer - see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer Thank you.

I tried your way of adding " ' ", but when I want to transform that CSV to JSON I have to add a step again to remove that " ' " from JSON.

I thought of another alternative giving space between the numbers like we used to see phone numbers in forms and Excels i.e. 12345 5678 so this will also add a professional look.

